# Многоточие, если не текст не умещается

Tags: javascript, html, css

Превращаю не вместившиеся слова в ... необходимо чтобы по нажатию на это многоточие выходило модальное окно, но как сделать возможность нажимать на многоточие?

[image: многоточие]

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
overflow: hidden;
```

}

Comment: Такое сокращение тегов и поведение лучше реализовать через JS, то есть допустим у тебя список и там 9 тегов, ты показываешь первые 3, ну и рядом троеточие который по нажатию дорендерит остальные 6

Comment: @E1mir благодарю за ответ!